# unix timestamps and php

Tags: php, mysql, strtotime, timestamp

I have a list of unix timestamps in a database, and I wanting to select the ones that are from today.

i.e If today is Tueday, I want to get all the timestamps that were made today? Is it possible? Is there such a things as `strtotime("Today")`?

Any help would be great

Comment: You can assume it is Mysql, since not specified otherwise ;)

Comment: @TBH: well, I did. But some *person* was taking rep points away for the assumption.

Comment: I am sorry, I made it by mistake. Already fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [mktime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to generate the timestamp for the start of the day and then find the database entries with a timestamp greater than that.

Comment: Also, you can use `getdate()` as your information source for `mktime()`, setting the values to 0 for the time.  (I make the sole assumption that you work in UTC values and only do time zone conversion for display purposes.)

Answer (score 2):

```
$start = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00')); // Current date, at midnight
$end = strtotime(date('Y-m-d 23:59:59')); // Current date, at 11:59:59 PM
```

then, you can just select where the timestamp is between the above 2 timestamps:

```
"SELECT FROM `foo` WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN '{$start}' and '{$end}'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the unix timestamps to sql dates in the SQL using `FROM_UNIXTIME()`, then compare those to `NOW()`

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`dateFld`)) = DATE(NOW());
```

Comment: FROM_UNIXTIME() is a MySQL only function. sea_1987 doesn't say what DBMS he's got.

Comment: Fair enough, you know what they say about assumptions!

Comment: @symcbean is absolutely right, but when the language is PHP, mySQL is a good guess statistically.

Answer (score 0):

Check if DAY(NOW()) and MONTH(NOW()) and YEAR(NOW()) is equal to appropriate value of DAY(timestamp) and MONTH(timestamp) and YEAR(timestamp).

```
select timestamp from table where DAY(NOW()) = DAY(timestamp) AND MONTH(NOW()) = MONTH(timestamp) AND YEAR(NOW()) = YEAR(timestamp)
```

Comment: That won't work - the original post states that the date is stored as a unix timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(NOW()) = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestampcol))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`FROM_UNIXTIME(somefield)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) can be compared to [`CURDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)() assuming you're using MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(datefield,'%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE();
```

ETA:
Okay, I was assailed by doubt when this answer was marked down. So I went and did a couple of tests.  Given MySQL it definitely works.  So why the downmod?

Consider this test which outputs 2 identical fields for every row in a table:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()),'%Y-%m-%d')  a , CURDATE() b
  FROM tablewithsomerows 
  WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()),'%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE();
```